# Create Grid/Table of Aligned Text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

G'day!

I'd like to make the following very simple table in Flutter. Basically two columns of text, left column is right-aligned, right column left-aligned. Each row top-aligned in case the right column has multiple names.

The left column should auto-size to the size of the largest item (since will have translation strings for each title), leaving the rest of the space for the right column names.

[image]

The black border and inner dashed borders are not necessary and only to show the alignments. The text is also just sample text.

I can create this in c# xaml in 2 minutes using a Grid with GridRow and GridColumn definitions, but seems very difficult in Flutter. I've tried using Table, DataTable and Columns/Rows, but none will align like this.

Surely this is a rather common way to display data?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Damian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `Table` widget to achieve the desired result.

For first column to be left-aligned and second to be right-aligned, although I didn't find any inbuilt property of `Table` widget that does the job for us, but we can still make use of `Container` widget and use `padding` and `alignment` to make them right and left aligned respectively for each `TableRow`, as below:

```
TableRow( children: [
                Column(
                  children:[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text('Officers:')
                  )
                ]),
                Column(children:[
                  Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text('Michael')
                  )
                ]),
              ]),
              TableRow( children: [
                Column(
                  children:[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text('Explorers:')
                  )
                ]),
                Column(children:[
                  Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text('James Smith \nFred Jones')
                  )
                ]),
              ]),
```

This will be rendered as:

[image]

- For each row to be top-aligned, we will use `Table's` `defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.top` property, so that in case of multiple values in right column, the row will be top-aligned:

[image]

- For left column to be auto-size based on data in it, we will use `columnWidth` property that takes `key` `value` pair as input to represent each row in the table and pass `IntrinsicColumnWidth()` which sizes the column according to size of its content, as below:

> ```
> columnWidths: {
>                   0: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
>                   1: IntrinsicColumnWidth()
>                 },
> ```

This renders the complete table as:

[image]

Hope this answers your question.